# How to group all values that have the same key into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

First, sorry if you find the question confusing.
Basically, I have an object like this:

```
[{"6":6.5},{"4":4.2},{"6":6.3}]
```

What I want to do, is to remove the duplicated keys but keep there values and push them all into one unique key only, as an array. like this:

```
[{"6":[6.5, 6.3]}, {"4": 4.2}]
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Why keep it as an array, why not `{"6": [...], "4": [...]}`?

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to vary whether the value is an array or number, be consistent. So the second object should be `{"4": [4.2]}`.

Comment: @Barmar: Not a duplicate. The keys can vary dynamically.

Comment: Oops, I got it wrong this time.

Comment: Yes, the key can vary dynamically. And sorry, the exact form that I want is {"6": [...], "4": [...]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.reduce()` is what you want:

```js
var data = [{"6":6.5},{"4":4.2},{"6":6.3}];

var res = data.reduce((rv, obj) => {
  var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  
  rv[key] = rv[key] || [];
  rv[key].push(obj[key]);
  
  return rv;
}, {});


console.log(res);
```

**Note:** This returns data always in the format of arrays (Even if there is one value). If you're looking for the exact format you specified, you just need to add more logic as I've demonstrated below (Although, I wouldn't recommend this approach, as it adds more complication down the line.)

```js
var data = [{"6":6.5},{"4":4.2},{"6":6.3}];

var res = data.reduce((rv, obj) => {
  var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  
  if (Array.isArray(rv[key])) { // Already is an array
    rv[key].push(obj[key]);
  } else if (rv[key] !== undefined) { // Has a value. Convert to array
    rv[key] = [rv[key], obj[key]];
  } else { // Haven't seen this key yet. Set the value
    rv[key] = obj[key];
  }
  
  return rv;
}, {});


console.log(res);
```